# Merge stereo channels into one side?

Tags: windows-7, audio, headphones, stereo, mono

I'm listening to stereo music albums in a pair of stereo headphones.  The left speaker of the headphones is not over my ear (I can't hear the left side).  The right speaker of the headphones is over my right ear.

The album I'm listening to has moments when only the left channel has audio.  The album is designed to be listened to by two ears.

How can I take all of the audio from both channels and listen to it w/ only one ear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 7 itself doesn't have any way to force mono audio output. However, some media players such as [Winamp](http://www.winamp.com/media-player/en) have this capability. If you're listening to your music in Winamp, you can press Ctrl+P to open the Preferences window, and then go to General Preferences > Playback and check "Force mono". Alternatively, you can use a program such as Audacity to re-encode the audio files in mono.

Comment: Keep in mind that while this is true, Winamp simply does not combine the channels to create mono, instead it re-samples it, so many audio files will get pings, cracks, and beeps in them, but not all. It's a bizarre and stupid implementation, combining them would've been so much easier. It may just be easier to buy a stereo to mono converter or switch to OS X where this feature is native.

Answer (score 0):

The program "Virtual Audio Cable" do this for all system (media player, internet browser, game etc.)
Install it, open "Audio Repeater" (KS) link and configure
Wave in: Virtual Cable 1
Wave out: 
Channel config: Mono
Press Start

Comment: Assuming this does solve the problem, could you improve your answer by specifying the website for information about it, and maybe even add some screenshots maybe?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for Windows OS' post XP**

1. Click on "**Start**" icon @lower-left corner [or press "Windows" button on keybd]
2. Search or navigate to "**Control Panel**" -- select it
3. Click on "**System**"
   [depending on the *system*, skip #3 and proceed directly to #4]
4. Click on "**Sound**"
5. Click on "**Playback**" tab [if it isnt's pre-selected]
6. Right-Click on the RealTek icon and select "**Properties**" [or regular-click "Properties" from this window]
7. Click on "**Levels**" tab
8. Click on "**Balance**"
9. **Turn the speaker you want up to 100; turn the one that's broken down to zero.**
   [the above step sends ALL sound to one speaker]
10. Click "**OK**" 3x to exit the maze.

Comment: Only useful if you have Realtek audio though...